# Need an example of a number in $\mathbb C^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a=(1,2,3,4,5)$  is an example of a vector in $\mathbb R^5$, what could be an example of a vector in $\mathbb C^5$ ?  is it $a=(1,2,3,4,i5)$ ?

Also, $x=a+ib$ is $2$ dimensional, can a complex number be one dimensional? like when $a=0$ or $b=0$, but if $b=0$ then it is a real number, so can we say that all real numbers (scalars) are one dimensional complex numbers?

Answer (score 2):

$$(1,i,1+i,3+2i,7i,\pi+\sqrt 2i)$$

Answer (score 1):

A vector in $\mathbb{C}^5$ is a vector of 5 elements $(x_1,\ldots,x_5)$, where each $x_i\in\mathbb{C}$.

About the dimensionality. This all depends on the base field you choose. It is true that $\mathbb{C}$ is two dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, thus $\mathbb{C}^5$ is 10 dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. However, when you take $\mathbb{C}$ as the base field, then $\mathbb{C}^5$ has dimension 5.

Answer (score 1):

A vector in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is anything of the form $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for $x_i \in \mathbb{P}$, so you $(1,2,3,4,5i)$ is indeed in $\mathbb{C}^5$ and so is any $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with all $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$ (remember $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$).

Dimensionality then depends on your field of scalars, i.e. the set of number you are allowed to multiply the vectors by. Over $\mathbb{R}$ $\{x = a + ib\}$ is 2 dimensional, but over $\mathbb{C}$ it is just 1 dimensional since we can hit every complex number by taking the number 1 as our basis vector and then multiplying it by any complex number.